# How to grant SELECT privilege to all views in snowflake with terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

Thanks for help in advance.

I started picking up a old terraform project from a friend, as well I am beginner too.

Unfortunately, I could not find how to grant SELECT privilege for all views in a schema

This is my code,

```
resource "snowflake_view_grant" "prod_view_select_grant" {
  provider      = snowflake.security_admin
  database_name = snowflake_database.prod_db.name
  schema_name   = "PRODUCTION"

  privilege = "SELECT"
  roles = [
    snowflake_role.role_1.name,
    snowflake_role.role_2.name,
    snowflake_role.role_3.name
  ]

  with_grant_option = false
}
```

There was no option mentioned in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/0.58.2/docs/resources/view_grant

Any workaround?

```
╷
│ Error: view_name must be set unless on_future is true
│ 
│   with snowflake_view_grant.prod_view_select_grant,
│   on tf_snowflake_grants.tf line 460, in resource "snowflake_view_grant" "prod_view_select_grant":
```

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question.

Comment: Sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Snowflake Terraform provider v0.58.2. If you upgrade to the latest version, you will have access to the `on_all` attribute. [See here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/view_grant#on_all):

> **on_all** (Boolean) When this is set to true and a schema_name is provided, apply this grant on all views in the given schema. When this is true and no schema_name is provided apply this grant on all views in the given database. The view_name and shares fields must be unset in order to use **on_all**. Cannot be used together with **on_future**.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade at this moment. Off course, I have seen this earlier.

Comment: @Hari, if you can't upgrade, then you could try using the `snowflake_views` data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/data-sources/views & then loop through each existing view in that database schema, using a `for_each` statement to create the grants.